# android.support.v7.RecyclerView causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

- OS = Linux Mint 17 KDE
- Android-Emul. = Genymotion
- Android-Stduio Version = 1.2.2

I am struggling with the new android-studio and importing recyclerview.

i have already tried many different ways to get recyclerview worked:

**activity_base.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

        <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/orange">

    </android.support.v7.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
package de.test.actionbarmd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.test.actionbarmd"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    //compile files('libs/recyclerview-v7-22.2.0.jar')    
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

i always get following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{de.test.actionbarmd/de.test.actionbarmd.BaseActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v7.RecyclerView
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23:
>   Error inflating class android.support.v7.RecyclerView
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v7.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/de.test.actionbarmd-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

am i doing something wrong or it is a bug in the new android -studio??

Comment: @BidhanA yes i have from Version 21.0.0 - 22.2.0!!! but even not specifying explicitly the Version-No. causes the same exception??!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`, you are missing the word `widget` in your layout hence the class would not be found,

Correct code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/orange">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```